# JSON Formatting - SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I've created a SharePoint list and applied JSON formatting to the 'New List Item' form, setting the layout into sections which all looks great.

I've created multiple list views but when editing the individual list item (via the form) in any view other than 'All Items' the conditional formatting I've applied to the columns doesn't come through.

I've checked all settings and tried to research online but am unable to find a solution. Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should repeat the same JSON on the rest views. When you applied formatting you used "Format Current View" . So that's why the rest are unaware of your JSON formatting.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting

You could always access all views you want and apply the same JSON via powershell script.